# cannot load data into datagridview C# for a multitable sql query

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I have a windows application C#

Where i have a datagridview1 where i need to retrieve a multitable data query
When the data is being retrieved from the table,it need to be filtered also at the same time
The problem that i am facing that the data is not been loaded although in the LocalWindows shows

The problem is The data is not being loaded in the datagridview
I can see the data is being loaded in the datagridview through the autos watch in visual studio-i have given the output in the end
what did i do wrong ?

```
   //CODE
   private void getData(string selectquery)
   {
       try
       {
          // string qryText1 = @"SELECT FEE_HEAD.FEE_HEAD_NAME, FEE_AMOUNT.FEE_HEAD_AMOUNT, FEE_AMOUNT.CLASS_ID FROM FEE_AMOUNT INNER JOIN FEE_HEAD ON FEE_AMOUNT.FEE_HEAD_ID = FEE_HEAD.ID";
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SRINATH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BFMS;Integrated Security=True");

         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectquery, con);
         con.Open();
         SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
         dataAdapter1.SelectCommand = command;
         DataTable dataT = new DataTable();
         dataAdapter1.Fill(dataT);
         BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
         bs.DataSource = dataT;
         dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
         dataAdapter1.Update(dataT);
         dataGridView1.Refresh();          
         con.Close();
       }
       catch (SqlException ex1)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex1.ToString());
       }
   }

  //LOCAL WATCH VIEW    

    Count   28  int+        Current {System.Data.DataRowView}   object {System.Data.DataRowView}
    DataMember  ""  string
    RowCount    29  int
    RowHeadersBorderStyle   Raised System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle
```

Comment: What happens if you bind `dataT` to `dataGridView1.DataSource`? What does your debugger watch shows for `dataGridView1.Rows.Count`? And for `dataT.Rows.Count`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use display the Columns for the Datagridview using

```
       dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "FEE_HEAD_NAME";
       ataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "FEE_HEAD_NAME";
       dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "FEE_HEAD_NAME";

       dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "FEE_HEAD_AMOUNT";
       dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "FEE_HEAD_AMOUNT";
       dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "FEE_HEAD_AMOUNT";
```

Anyways Thanks for the reply everyone

Answer (score 0):

the code is working perfectly

`public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string query = "select * from benefitplans";
            getData(query);
        }`

and then

```
private void getData(string selectquery)
    {
        try
        {
            // string qryText1 = @"SELECT FEE_HEAD.FEE_HEAD_NAME, FEE_AMOUNT.FEE_HEAD_AMOUNT, FEE_AMOUNT.CLASS_ID FROM FEE_AMOUNT INNER JOIN FEE_HEAD ON FEE_AMOUNT.FEE_HEAD_ID = FEE_HEAD.ID";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=392;User id=sa; Password=manage@123;Initial Catalog=Benefit;Pooling=False");


            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectquery, con);


            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
            dataAdapter1.SelectCommand = command;
            DataTable dataT = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter1.Fill(dataT);
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dataT;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
            dataAdapter1.Update(dataT);
            dataGridView1.Refresh();

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex1.ToString());
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: So what should be done in this case ! is there any formating error

Comment: no i just use your code and write a query and pass it to method and its working......try it again may it will work for you also...

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing these lines

```
     SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
     dataAdapter1.SelectCommand = command;
     DataTable dataT = new DataTable();
     dataAdapter1.Fill(dataT);
     BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
     bs.DataSource = dataT;
     dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
     dataAdapter1.Update(dataT);
     dataGridView1.Refresh();          
     con.Close();
```

with

```
     SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
     dataAdapter1.SelectCommand = command;
     DataSet dataS = new DataSet();
     dataAdapter1.Fill(dataS);
     dataGridView1.DataSource = dataS;
     con.Close();
```

Hope, this may help.

Comment: This did not help 
Is there any other way which could be used over here !!! to load the data.**I would need it to continue with other components of the project**